# Laravel 5.1, define constants from .ENV

Tags: php, laravel

I a php file I have this constants:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Define
{
    const HELLO = 1
    const STATE = 2;
    //etc
```

But I need that those values changes depending the `env(APP_ENV)` that I'm working.

For example (pseudocode):

```
if (APP_ENV==QA) 
  CONST HELLO = 1
else if (APP_ENV==PROD) 
  CONST HELLO = 2
```

How can I set up those constants?

EDIT: I was trying this:

Adding a `values.php` file to config folder, like this:

```
<?php

return [

    'myvalue' => env('APP_ENV',null),
];
```

Then in the php file use them with:

```
\Config::get('
```

But I can't use that while defining constants.

Comment: You can modify in the constructor of the class, by fetching env variables and applying your pseudo code in real

Comment: I get this while I'm trying: "Constant defined using the const keyword must be declared at the top-level scope"

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-constant-add.php

Comment: I can't install extra extensions, I'm not the admin of the server

Comment: Do they have to be class constants? If not, you can use `define()`

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
const HELLO = env('APP_ENV') == PROD ? 2 : 1
```

Comment: Expression is not allowed as class constant value

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up the app environment variable APP_ENV as you mentioned you should use it like this.

```
if (App::environment('local')) {
    // The environment is local
    return [
        'DB_NAME' => 'xyz'
    ];
}

if (App::environment(['local', 'staging'])) {
    // The environment is either local OR staging...
    return [
        'DB_NAME' => 'xyz_staging'
    ];
}
```

It is up to you how you want to receive/configure it. You can set global variables or receive it as an array.